# How to configure AWS apigateway proxy resource with HTTP proxy integration?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, http-proxy, api-gateway

Execution failed due to configuration error: Illegal character in path at index 46: http://petstore-demo-endpoint.execute-api.com/{proxy}?type=fish

Logs :

```
Execution log for request 965a6cd1-1f68-4b33-8bab-3741e40b0028
Fri Mar 20 08:19:39 UTC 2020 : Starting execution for request: 965a6cd1-1f68-4b33-8bab-3741e40b0028
Fri Mar 20 08:19:39 UTC 2020 : HTTP Method: GET, Resource Path: /test/petstore/pets
Fri Mar 20 08:19:39 UTC 2020 : Method request path: {proxy=petstore/pets}
Fri Mar 20 08:19:39 UTC 2020 : Method request query string: {type=fish}
Fri Mar 20 08:19:39 UTC 2020 : Method request headers: {}
Fri Mar 20 08:19:39 UTC 2020 : Method request body before transformations: 
Fri Mar 20 08:19:39 UTC 2020 : Endpoint request URI: http://petstore-demo-endpoint.execute-api.com/{proxy}?type=fish
Fri Mar 20 08:19:39 UTC 2020 : Endpoint request headers: {x-amzn-apigateway-api-id=ssg89ys6y6, User-Agent=AmazonAPIGateway_ssg89ys6y6}
Fri Mar 20 08:19:39 UTC 2020 : Endpoint request body after transformations: 
Fri Mar 20 08:19:39 UTC 2020 : Sending request to http://petstore-demo-endpoint.execute-api.com/{proxy}?type=fish
Fri Mar 20 08:19:39 UTC 2020 : Execution failed due to configuration error: Illegal character in path at index 46: http://petstore-demo-endpoint.execute-api.com/{proxy}?type=fish
Fri Mar 20 08:19:39 UTC 2020 : Method completed with status: 500
```

Comment: Actually i am trying to configure proxy for my ELB , i am getting the same error metioned above "Execution failed due to configuration error: Illegal character in path", so i tried to create a test proxy resource and i used the pets end point ,even with the test end point also i am geting the same error can some body help me on this?

Comment: Have you checked this?
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-proxy-path-character-error/

Comment: Hi @SurajBhatia thanks so much for your reply..i checked the link ..  I missed step 5". For Mapped from, enter method.request.path.proxy" . i fixed it now .thanks once again

Answer (score 1):

Adding this here for others who face the issue

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-proxy-path-character-error/